# The Application of Convolution and Delta Functions

Tags: probability, self-study, convolution

$$K=Z-(X+Y)$$

$Z$ is any discrete value. I applied convolution for PDF of two exponential random variables: $X$ and $Y$. Which is like that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Sum_of_two_i.i.d._exponential_random_variables). Now I need to compute PDF and expected value of $K$?

I learned that I can do it with delta function but I could not manage it.

I will appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: Could you be more specific about where you ran into trouble?  You have already done the hard part in finding the distribution of $X+Y$; now all you need to do is find the convolution of $Z$ and $-(X+Y)$ (and that scarcely needs the delta function, but presumably this is intended as an exercise in using the delta function, so please (1) include the [tag:self-study] tag and (2) look up [our posts about delta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22delta+function%22+convolution)).

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.